# Match making algorithm socket.io for game starting at fixed time

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making a game in which users can register and game starts at fixed time by (pair of 2) pairing users from the pool of players. I'm not able to understand how can I emit the start_game event for the game to start once the pairing is done as one player can be offline at the start of the game but the game needs to start and timeout the offline player.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to understand how can I emit the start_game event for the game to start once the pairing is done as one player can be offline at the start of the game but the game needs to start and timeout the offline player.

Here's one way to approach it.  Send the user a `start_game` message.  Set a `setTimeout()` for whatever your timeout time is.  When the client receives the `start_game` event, the client needs to immediately respond with something like `start_game_received`.  If you don't get a `start_game_received` before the  `setTimeout()` fires, then time out that user and revoke their match making.  When the `start_game_received` is received, you check if the timer is running.  If it is, you cancel the timer.

This requires keeping a bit of server-side state for a given user.  You can do that with a custom property on their socket.io `socket` that contains an object with their state in it.  For example, you can store the timer there and a boolean indicating whether they've already been invited to a match or not.